# Cannot remove ubuntu as a boot option

Tags: uefi

I followed the instructions at:
[How do I remove "Ubuntu" in the bios boot menu? (UEFI)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/63610/how-do-i-remove-ubuntu-in-the-bios-boot-menu-uefi), but ubuntu keeps on reappearing as a boot option. Is there a way to fix this?
Edit: Is it also possible to format the efi partition? 
Edit 2: I can remove it, but the next time it reboots, it reappears.

Comment: Please provide context: Why do you want to remove this entry? Have you completely removed Ubuntu from your computer? If you have an Ubuntu installation on an EFI-based computer, chances are you need the `ubuntu` entry, or at least an entry to some other EFI boot loader for Linux, to boot Ubuntu.

Comment: @RodSmith I already remove ubuntu from my computer. When you select "ubuntu" as the boot manager, it opens up into a minimal bash interface.

Comment: It's not Bash, it's GRUB. In Windows, you might try [EasyUEFI](http://www.easyuefi.com/index-us.html) -- although I've never used it myself, just know it exists and might do what you need. If you boot an Ubuntu live CD, you could use `efibootmgr` to do the trick. You'll need to first identify your Ubuntu entry (`sudo efibootmgr`), then use the `-B` option to remove it (as in `sudo efibootmgr -b 5 -B` to delete entry #5, if that's it).

Answer (score 1):

The solution was to remove the Ubuntu folder from the efi partition.

Answer (score 0):

All you have to do is remove manually the Ubuntu in UEFI menu. If there's not such option, you should contact the manufacturer. And there's no need to format the EFI partition, I recommend that you don't even try to do it because that's quite risky.

Comment: I removed it via the uefi, it dissappear as an option, but the next time you go to the uefi setup, it reappears.

Comment: That's weird, try to reset the UEFI to the factory settings.